# Django database relationship - TypeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

I am 3 days trying to make the relationship One to Many with the database using the table "Alternativas" through the resposta of the table  "Questoes". I want to make a quiz system, where the questions are stored in a table in the DB, and the answers is in another table and in this way make a relationship between them, but it return's the following error when trying to pull the response column, follow's the print.

[image]

models.py:

```
class Questoes(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    enunciado = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    alternativa_correta = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    resposta = models.ManyToOneRel('resposta', to='Alternativas', 
    field_name='descricao')

class Alternativas(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    questao_id = models.ForeignKey('Questoes', on_delete=CASCADE, 
    db_column="questao_id")
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

Views.py:

```
def dashboard(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        questoes = {}
        questoes['questoes'] = Questoes.objects.get(id=1)
        print('=======================================================================')
        print(questoes)
        print('=======================================================================')
        for a in questoes.resposta:
            print(a)
        print('======================================================================')
```

Comment: please replace image with text just copy past it from console

Comment: What are you going to store in `resposta` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ManyToOneRel is not a field. It is an internal class, part of the implementation of relationships, and not something you should use in your models.

You already have a many-to-one relationship between those models, because you defined `questao_id` in Alternativas. Remove that ManyToOneRel definition and in your view use the reverse relation:

```
for a in questoes.alternativas_set.all():
```